# Removing a block of text using powershell

Tags: powershell

So I need to remove a few blocks of txt in multiple txt files. The files look like this:

```
Header
Value
Data
   <DefaultValue>
       sdf
         asdfsdf
       asfkfkf
   </DefaultValue>
Data3
Data2
   <DefaultValue>
       sdfdffff
          asdfsasdfddf
       asfkf
   </DefaultValue>**
Dat
End
```

I need to remove the block of lines that begin with **DefaultValue** and end with **/DefaultValue**

The result should look like this:

```
Header
Value
Data
Data3
Data2
Dat
End
```

Unfortunately it is not a properly formed XML file so XML node removal won't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this to get around the need to add a third party Join-String function:

```
$filePath = '.\Desktop\new  3.txt'
$text = ""
Get-Content $filePath | % {$text += $_ + "NEWLINE"}
$text = $text -Replace "<Default.+?DefaultValue>",""
$text.Replace("NEWLINE","`r`n")
```

To yield:

```
Header
Value
Data

Data3
Data2
   **
Dat
End
```

To make this repetitive, you'd want to do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\logs\ -Filter "*.txt" | % {
    $text = ""
    Get-Content $_.FullName | % {$text += $_ + "NEWLINE"}
    $text = $text -Replace "<Default*DefaultValue>",""
    $text.Replace("NEWLINE","`r`n") | Out-File $_.FullName -Force
}
```

Good luck, back your data up, and check back for more elegant answers from another user.