# Powershell to remove a block of text from an HTML file (or variable)

Tags: powershell

I have a number of HTML files and am trying to remove a specific block of text using powershell.
This block appears in every table.

```
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div id="reportbody">*TEXT*<a target="_blank" href=*LINK*</a></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

I can do a -replace on the 3rd line to stop the text/link displaying but I see a blank row in the tables.
I have tried something similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850761/removing-a-block-of-text-using-powershell) but I have no unique start/finish markers.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
$regex = 
@'
(?ms)\s*<tr>\s*
\s*<td colspan="3">\s*
\s*<div id="reportbody">\*TEXT\*<a target="_blank" href=\*LINK\*</a></div>\s*
\s*</td>\s*
\s*</tr>\s*
'@



(Get-Content ./file.htm -raw) -replace $regex |
 Set-Content ./newfile.htm
```

Comment: Excellent many thanks mjolinor.
I couldn't get my head round the multi-line regex.